# How to HIDE mySQL error from displaying at interface?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this error in my webpage.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'like ''' at line 1

However, I want to ignore this error because it does not influence my output.
Therefore, I want to hide this error from displaying on user side.

I tried to use this code `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);`to hide this error, but only can hide "notice" error.

Any suggestion / solution to hide above error?

Comment: You could try fixing it instead?

Comment: **Fix your syntax error.**

Comment: "It does not influence my output"? Well, then you can just skip the offending sql query, can you.

Comment: "However, I want to ignore this error because it does not influence my output." It surely should be affecting your output. So be careful.

Comment: We need more info - are you using PDO, MySQL or MySQLI ?

Comment: I will use the code in next step, so i do not want to delete.
I know what cause the error, but I want use the code for next step.

However, during first step, the error notification prompt out and influenced my interface, i just want to hide the error.

Comment: @rynah I just want to hide the error from displaying.

Comment: @user1281385 I am using MySQL, phpmyadmin

Comment: @HauYeenLance: Then check which step it is and don’t run the query if it’s not the right one‽

Comment: @rynah i need to run the code later, so i need the code, i just want to hide the error message.

Comment: @HauYeenLance: So *check which step it is in the code*.

Comment: @Hau-Yeen-Lance Yes MySQL but what method of connection ?

Comment: @user1281385 I am not sure am I answering your question.

I used this
<?php
$hostname_conn = "localhost";
$database_conn = "eresident";
$username_conn = "root";
$password_conn = "";
$conn = mysql_pconnect($hostname_conn, $username_conn, $password_conn) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
?>

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, You can use "@" sign before function call to prevent from showing any errors.
Example,

```
$result = @$mysqli->query($query);
```

But I would strongly suggest fixing that error.

Comment: I want to use that query in the next process.
This error prompt out because user has not key-in the data yet.
So, I just want to hide the error from displaying.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone suggested, ignoring errors is bad practice; it will hinder your project when new requirements will be implemented etc. or when you (or your replacement) will debug it 6 months from now...

alter code so if user did not enter data, the query is not processed eg:

```
if($_POST) mysql_query($query,$conn);
```

also, I always ensure that actual error messages NEVER DISPLAY, I show a random string i can look up in my code, so if it ever shows, it does not disclose any database information to potential hackers.

```
$result = mysql_query($query,$conn) or die("HYGTR564dfREFH");
```